# Rails cancan(can) not recognizing data in test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have a thorough `ability.rb` defined that's working properly.  However, when I write a controller spec that sends a request to an endpoint, cancan(can) repeatedly returns a 403.

In my `ability.rb` in the respective section for handling the endpoint I'm testing, when outputting `{Model}.all.to_json` it's outputting an empty array.

How can I fix this so that it recognizes the data in my test database, or change my test to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

The data in the test database is reset on each iteration. If you want to use some specific state (e.g. data), you must re-create that state as part of the test.

Depending on the test framework, use the `before` or `setup` hook to create the data you need in the test suite before the test itself is executed.

Answer (score 0):

After going through a deep stare down of my code, I realized that one bit of data I wasn't creating through fixtures was failing validation, thus not being created.

My testing environment was setup properly, but I didn't have a `create!` call but rather a `create`, causing it not to be explicit with the validation errors.